# Property with custom setter but default getter

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the best practice?

- Declare the property as nonatomic
- Create custom getter too
- Another possibility that I'm not aware of

and why prefer one of this solution rather another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most of the cases, you just need to provide implementation for setter and declare the property as nonatmoic. This will generate ivar with underscore prefix and you need to set the value in setter method.

You don't normally need to override getter unless you have special logic in getter or the property need to be atomic.

If you do want to provide getter (along with setter), you may need a backend ivar either by declare it in `@implementation{ /*here*/ }` or use `@synthesize` to generate one.

In case for atomic property:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@property (atomic) id object; // atomic is default attribute 
@end
@implementation MyClass
@synthesize object = _object; // to create ivar
- (id)object {
@synchronized(self) { // or use lock / atomic compare-and-swap
    return _object;
}
}
- (void)setObject:(id)obj {
@synchronized(self) {  // or use lock / atomic compare-and-swap
    _object = obj;
}
}

@end
```

Comment: "In most of the cases, you just need to provide implementation for setter and declare the property as nonatmoic."
That's exactly what I use now. So I will continue to use this. Thanks for your answer.